# Is there a way to do 'query execution plan ' in Firebase database? Similar to the usage of explain() in MongoDB?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

Is there a way to validate execution cost of a query in Firebase database? Similar to the usage of explain() in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no query execution explanation in Firebase Database. To be honest, the types of queries you can currently build on the database are limited. So such a tool would be fairly static.

If you're not getting the results you expect or the performance you expect, share the [minimal code to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we'll help from there.